# Insert or update realm content based on objects inner attribute changes

Tags: android, realm

My data model looks like this:

**Dummy**:

- id: String
- title: String
- content: List

  - object1
  - object2
  - object3
    ...

Lets image I've a table "Dummy" in realm, where I have 4 Dummy objects. I do a sync from backend and receive 4 Dummy objects, but this time, the first Dummy object has different content - for instance 2 more items. I would like to update local DB with new content. I tried to use `insertOrUpdate` and `copyOrUpdate`, but they did not work. Then I thought - maybe I should just delete Dummy table and insert new data - turns out, I can't even do that (commented code does not work). Any ideas on how to succeed and what am I missing?

```
private fun storeDataToLocalDB(data: ArrayList<Dummy>) {
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realmInstance ->
            realmInstance.executeTransaction {
                realm ->
                    //val result: RealmResults<Dummy> = realm
                            //.where(Dummy::class.java)
                            //.findAll()
                    //result.deleteAllFromRealm()

                    realm.insertOrUpdate(data)
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Does your backend sends you a unique id for each Dummy ?